# connection error in socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm doing a project i my networks class and I'm facing a problem in my code. that is my code is not accepting the connection. in the picture you can see the problem and here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WebServer {
public static void main(String args[]) {
WebServer ws = new WebServer();
ws.start();
}

protected void start() {
ServerSocket s;
Socket remote;

System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 8080");

try {

  s = new ServerSocket(8080);

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  return;
}

  try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for connection ");
     remote = s.accept();
    System.out.println("Connection, sending data. ");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    remote.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());


    String str = ".";
    while (!str.equals("")){
      str = in.readLine();
    }

    out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    out.println("Server: Bot");

    out.println("");

    out.println("<H1>Welcome to the Ultra Mini-WebServer</H2>");
    out.flush();
    remote.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }

  }
  }
```

I think there is a problem in the accept function? or should i implement also a recv function? What [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsskQ.png)I need from the code is to a chat between the client and the web server.

Comment: You may want to fix your formatting.

Comment: @liquidsystem `accept()` is a method belonging to `ServerSocket`, its not one he should or needs to have written

Comment: I see that now, I fixed my comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: What are you using as a client to connect to your server?

Answer (score 0):

This code sends a jpeg file and works fine for me:

```
public class FileServer { 
    static BufferedInputStream bis;
    static BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    static ServerSocket ss = null;
    static Socket s = null;
    static int handler = 0;
    static byte[] buffer= new byte[1024];

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException  {
            ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
            System.out.println("Waiting");
            s = ss.accept();


            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("b.jpg"));
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream( ));
            while((handler= bis.read(buffer))!=-1){
                    bos.write(buffer,0,handler);
                    System.out.println("Sending");
            }
            System.out.println("File Written Successfully");
            bis.close();
            bos.close();

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> that is my code is not accepting the connection.

Your code is accepting a connection. When I try e. g. `nc localhost 8080`, I get

```
Webserver starting up on port 8080
Waiting for connection 
Connection, sending data.
```

So, the problem must be in your client or on the way to the server.